# hardcoded wp pages/plugins problems

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

Ok so long story short, ive been handed a WP site that amongst a few minor changes, needs two specific plugins installed ASAP for the project to be complete. the menu amongst other things is hard coded. each page is also a separate page not feeding from single/page.php"...so if he has about us page etc...its a seperate "about-us.php" page. each menu item lead to their respective "---.php" pages and what the developer did is

"hooked" and styled certain parts of WordPress into each separate page. (like sidebar for eg)
so it provides half dynamism and half whatever he hard coded in there.

the problem is that, the plugins i need to install,(jq lightbox,and image magnify zoom thingy) dont work. no matter what i do, its just a no go. When i click on the images, they just go to a blank page.

now when i install them in a sample WP site i have and use to test things b4 i implement, it works as it should. Ive also thereafter tested on my own custom wp site from a side client and plugins also worked there.

My boss knows im doing the research but this is a proj that was supposed to have BEEN done.
ANy ideas as to how i can add/make work these plugins in this type of wp environment?? or is it not possible if not using the single/page.php?

i CAN redo the whole site in my own manner but thatll take more time than i have so

is there any further troubleshooting / fixes that i can do to get these plugins working?
or is there any changes i can put on these seperate pages thatll allow me to use said plugins?

the link to the page the developer designed/developed is http://maglovir.com/

Any tips/links/help in general i humbly appreciate. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of plugins inject some code into `wp_head()` therefore you need to ensure this is included in header.php. Check, if its not included, add it just before the closing `</head>` like so:

```
    ...
    ...
    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: god you NAILED IT!!!!!!!!!!! THANK YOU! youve saved me lol.